# Stop implicit wildcard in Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, file, directory, filter

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathName, "*.xml");
```

Also returns files like `foo.xml_`  Is there a way to force it to not do so, or will I have to write code to filter the return results.

This is the same behavior as `dir *.xml` on the command prompt, but different than searching for `*.xml` in windows explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is by design. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) (look at the note section and examples given):

> A searchPattern with a file extension
>   of exactly three characters returns
>   files having an extension of three or
>   more characters, where the first three
>   characters match the file extension
>   specified in the searchPattern.

You could limit it as follows:

**C# 2.0:**

```
string[] fileEntries = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(pathName,  "*.xml"),
    delegate(string file) {
        return String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(file), ".xml", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;
    });
 // or
string[] fileEntries = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(pathName,  "*.xml"),
    delegate(string file) {
        return Path.GetExtension(file).Length == 4;
    });
```

**C# 3.0:**

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathName, "*.xml").Where(file =>
   Path.GetExtension(file).Length == 4).ToArray();
// or
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathName, "*.xml").Where(file =>
    String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(file), ".xml",
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Any idea of the reason for this seemingly bizarre behaviour? Legacy 8.3 filename stuff?

Comment: I'm targeting the 2.0 framework so I can't use the => syntax.

Comment: @Dan: updated code to use an anonymous delegate. @Jon Seigel: yep, that's correct. Another note on the MSDN link mentions that the method "checks against file names with both the 8.3 file name format and the long file name format."

Comment: Your first C#2.0 has a *.txt where it should be *.xml.  Otherwise it does exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dan: thanks, updated. I was testing locally with .txt files and missed it here :)

Answer (score 3):

it's due to the 8.3 search method of windows. If you try to search for "*.xm" you'll get 0 results.

you can use this in .net 2.0:

```
string[] fileEntries = 
Array.FindAll<string>(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathName, "*.xml"), 
            new Predicate<string>(delegate(string s)
            {
                return System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s) == ".xml";
            }));
```